# How to get validation result?

Tags: jquery, validation

I use jQuery validator plugin from this link :

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/instant-input-validation.html#google_vignette

Everything works fine, but when I press  submit button, I want get result from

$("#validate").inputValidation();

To make sure everything is correct.
How can this be done?

i not use form jus div id this my code :

```
<div class="tab-content" id="validate">
                    
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="popular" role="tabpanel"
 aria-labelledby="popular-tab">
                      
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="field-regm form-inner mb-30">
<label>name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="validate" data-validate-type="minlength" data-constraint="3"  autofocus  minlength="3" maxlength="100" placeholder="name here">

</div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="field-regm form-inner mb-30">
<label>mobile</label>
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="validate" data-validate-type="phoneUS"  pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="02XXXXXXXX">

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-inner">
<button class="primary-btn2" type="submit">add</button>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
    
$("#validate").inputValidation();
        
</script>
```

Thanks ,

Comment: Is it possible to validation input boxes without a form like div id?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the validation only works for the `form` element and your code `$("#validate")` is a `div`.

Use the function `valid()` after validating the form with `validate`.

Hope this helps!

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
var form = $("#validate");
form.validate();
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#demo").html("Valid: " + form.valid());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">


<form class="tab-content" id="validate">

  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="popular" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="popular-tab">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="field-regm form-inner mb-30">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="validate" data-validate-type="minlength" data-constraint="3" autofocus minlength="3" maxlength="100" placeholder="name here" required>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="field-regm form-inner mb-30">
        <label>mobile</label>
        <input type="tel" maxlength="10" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="validate" data-validate-type="phoneUS" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="02XXXXXXXX">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-inner">
        <button class="primary-btn2" type="submit">add</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I did not succeed, so I added my code to the question